Story about youths in dystopian-type society who live in an old trash landfill & essentially become scavengers
I read this sometime in the 90s, so it could have been published pretty much anytime pre-2000. I think it's something relatively obscure book rather than anything especially popular.
It was about some sort of dystopian-type society where I the poor lived in old trash landfills, which they scavenged for items of everyday use, things for trade, food etc.
There may have been a character who was living in a gated house in the highly secured & militarized gated neighborhoods that people with money lived in.
There may have been some sort of street chase that happens between characters at some point.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

For example, who was the hero? What was his/their name/s? Was there a villain? Where did they live (e.g. the future, an alternative universe entirely? another planet?). What trash did they salvage, and who was buying it from them? What did they do with the money they got for salvage? How old were the kids? How did they meet the character from the gated house? What was his name? Who was chasing them? Did they escape?

Invitation to the Game by Monica Hughes? Teenagers leaving education are given a basic stipend, and have to find accommodation and furnishings for themselves. They end up living in a warehouse.

Stig of the Dump, Kipling.
